# Dropwizard client deal with self signed certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, dropwizard, jersey-client

Quite new with Dropwizard.

I found a lot of solution to deal with Jersey and ssl self signed certificate.
Dropwizard version is 0.9.2

I have tried to set a SSLContext but I get

```
The method sslContext(SSLContext) is undefined for the type JerseyClientBuilder
```

Code:

```
   TrustManager[] certs = new TrustManager[]{
          new X509TrustManager() {
              @Override
              public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                  return null;
              }

              @Override
              public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                      throws CertificateException {
              }

              @Override
              public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                      throws CertificateException {
              }
          }
  };

  public static class TrustAllHostNameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {

      public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
          return true;
      }

  }
  private Client getWebClient(AppConfiguration configuration, Environment env) {
      SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
      ctx.init(null, certs, new SecureRandom());
      Client client = new JerseyClientBuilder(env)
          .using(configuration.getJerseyClient())
          .sslContext(ctx)
          .build("MyClient");
      return client;
  }
```

The configuration part:

```
private JerseyClientConfiguration jerseyClient = new JerseyClientConfiguration();

public JerseyClientConfiguration getJerseyClient() {
    return jerseyClient;   
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found a simple solution just using the configuration

```
jerseyClient:
  tls:
    verifyHostname: false
    trustSelfSignedCertificates: true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think to create an insecure client in 0.9.2 you would use a Registry of ConnectionSocketFactory, something like...

```
    final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

    sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
                    throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
            }
            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
                    throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
            }
            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }
        } }, new SecureRandom());


    final SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory =
            new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

    final Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
            .register("https", sslConnectionSocketFactory)
            .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.INSTANCE)
            .build();

    builder.using(registry);

    Client client = new JerseyClientBuilder(env)
      .using(configuration.getJerseyClient())
      .using(registry)
      .build("MyInsecureClient");
```